# MySQL Query: Order childs after their parents

Tags: mysql

I have a table with:

[image]

Can I with a single query organize it to show:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could do this bastardization:

```
ORDER BY CASE parentid WHEN 0 THEN id ELSE parentid END ASC, id ASC
```

I say it's a bastardization because it requires a computation for every single row.  It will not be performant.  The better way to solve this problem would be to use a better datamodel.  Instead of storing just parent ids, you can also store using a [Nested Set Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model).  So basically your datamodel would look like:

```
id | parentid | name   | left | right
1  | 0        | Peter  | 1    | 4
2  | 0        | Marcus | 5    | 8
3  | 1        | Monica | 2    | 3 
4  | 2        | Sergei | 6    | 7
```

Now, with that, your order would be reduced to:

```
ORDER BY `left` ASC
```

Which would do the exact same thing.  Give that nested set article a read.  There are better ways to solve the problem than just parentid if you need to get data out either filtered or sorted...

Comment: Finally I only introduced a 'sorting' column instead of 'left' and 'right' columns.

Comment: I also found this very interesting article: http://sqllessons.com/categories.html using adjacency list model.